# How to access rule data in PROLOG

Tags: prolog

I have to determine whether two rectangles overlap or not, I can do this but I am struggling with figuring out how to grab my given data, and compare it to eachother to determine larger values.

```
%This is :what would be happening :
%separate(rectangle(0,10,10,0), rectangle(4,6,6,4))

separate(R1,R2) :-
    %I Have to figure out how to take the values from R1 and R2 and compare
    %them to one another.
.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called "pattern matching".

```
separated(R1, R2) :-
    R1 = rectangle(A1, B1, C1, D1),
    R2 = rectangle(A2, B2, C2, D2),
    /* now just use your As and Bs */
```

and in many cases it is better to write straight away:

```
separated(rectangle(A1, B1, C1, D1), rectangle(A2, B2, C2, D2)) :-
    /* now just use your As and Bs */
```